# Safari not displaying content beyond visible height

Tags: html, css

[image]

When i scrolled to the bottom of page, i observed that bottom border and other content below the table are not rendered (But they are in DOM). Only The content in visible height is rendered. When i clicked on the empty space below the table, the remaining showed up. What could be the reason.

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
    {{#light-table table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table" height='75vh' totalWidth=1200 as |t|}}
       {{t.head class="tableGrid" fixed=true}}
        {{#t.body multiSelect=true as |body|}} {{/t.body}}
    {{/light-table}}
</div>
```

i tried adding `overflow:scroll` on wrapper around the table. which did not work. This is happening only in safari

Answer (score 0):

try putting the fixed height and overflow on a wrapper to the table.  table's won't scroll / work with overflows, so you need to wrap a table in a containing element with the scroll behavior and fixed height that you want.

```html
<div style="height: 100px; overflow: auto">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```